# Exclude submit button from beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I'm **detecting form changes** in a page, and so i've handled

```
$('#element').change(function(){
metaDataChange = true;
});
```

so that when the user **leaves the page** and a **change was made** in an input in a form. He/she will be alerted **whether to leave or to stay on the page**, just like in Facebook where you try to post a status and then you leave the page, a dialog box will be prompted giving you options to either leave or stay in the page.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {

    if(metaDataChange === true || basicInfoChange === true){
        return "You have unsaved changes, do you want to leave without saving?";       
    }
});
```

The code above works well however.. i want to exclude the submit button for this.
Because when i click **"submit"** and the behavior of the submit button means redirecting to another page. The user is prompted again with the same message when in fact he/she intends to save his/her changes.

**How do i exclude the submit button** from being caught in the beforeunload event of the window? I can hardly explain this... i hope it can be understood..Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
metaDataChange = false;
...redirecting 
});
```

Comment: Why didn't i thought of this! This works! Thank You sir.. can you give me an idea how it worked? i mean two events .click() and .on('beforeunload') are both triggered by the submit button, how come the .click() button gets to change the variable 'metaDataChange' first before the 'beforeunload' gets it?i thought they are executed simultaneously?

Comment: @YiiNewbie The click event happens first, because that's what actually happened - the user clicked on the element. Now, if we don't cancel it in some way, the default action is to redirect to another page - but that doesn't happen until the click event has been processed and falls through to the default (built-into-the-browser) handler. If a click handler returns false, for example, the default behavior is also cancelled.